# Request timeout using cordova-plugin-advanced-http

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I am using the advanced plugin to make calls to a legacy api that can’t implement a cors policy.
My problem is that even if i set a timeout the request doesn’t seem to respect that number and throws lots of errors of connection timeout after 10000ms and other errors, like this:

**status:-2,error:TLS connection could not be established: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Read error: ssl=0x752c6976c8: I/O error during system call**

**status:-3,error:Host could not be resolved: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host**

**status:-4,error:Request timed out: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to ... after 10000ms**

Did any one experienced this, and how did you mitigated the problem?

Here is my code:

```
constructor(private nHttp: HTTP) { }
get(url, customParameters, customHeaders) {
    this.nHttp.setRequestTimeout(30);
    return this.nHttp.get(url, customParameters, customHeaders);
}
```